# core-data : only the last object can be initialized correctly in a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

My model has two entities `Artist` and `Album`, and `Album` has a `Artist` instance member. I used following code to pre-populate my model but only found the last Album , that is `ablum3`, have set up a correct association with the `Artist Beatles`. For `album1`,`album2`, the `artist` filed are `nil`.

There must be something wrong which I did not spot...

```
//create  an artist
NSManagedObject *artist = [NSEntityDescription
                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Artist"
                           inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext]; 

[artist setValue:@"Beatles" forKey:@"name"];

//populate the data
NSArray *albums = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"album1",@"album2",@"album3", nil];
for (NSString *title in albums){
    //populate the data
    NSManagedObject *album = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Album"
                              inManagedObjectContext:__managedObjectContext]; 

    [album setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
    [album setValue:artist forKey:@"artist"];
}
```

Comment: How does your relationship look like? Say something about the model.

Comment: @Flex , inspired by our answer, I checked my model. The problem fixed by rectifying it as an to-many relationship between Artist and Album. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without no further detail, it's difficult to know what is going on. I try to understand the model on what you have written.

So, this model works for me

[image]

`albums` is a to-many relationships to `Album`. Furthermore it's optional, you can have `Artist` with no `Album`.

`artist` is the inverse rel for Artist. one-to-one cardinality. It's required since you cannot have an `Album` without an `Artist`.

Here the code:

```
- (void)populateDB
{
    //create  an artist
    NSManagedObject *artist = [NSEntityDescription
                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Artist"
                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; 

    [artist setValue:@"Beatles" forKey:@"name"];

    //populate the data
    NSArray *albums = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"album1",@"album2",@"album3", nil];
    for (NSString *title in albums){
        //populate the data
        NSManagedObject *album = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Album"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]; 

        [album setValue:title forKey:@"title"];
        [album setValue:artist forKey:@"artist"];
    }
}
```

After having called `populatedDB`, save the context calling `[self saveContext]`

```
- (void)saveContext {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (moc != nil) {
        if ([moc hasChanges] && ![moc save:&error]) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}
```

If you need to arrange your model let me know.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The to-many relationship is probably the key here. If it was to-one instead of to-many, you'd get the behaviour @pierr described.

Comment: @JesseRusak I agree. For this reason I commented first. I'm waiting for a confirmation by pierr. Cheers.